# ActiveRecord validation: Validate on model.new()

Tags: ruby, activerecord, mongoid

So this is my scenario:

ModelN has to refer to ModelA's collection in Mongo to validate itself. ModelA contains the 'rule' for ModelB to be validated against. ModelA has three fields, two of which are the combined keys which help it identify the rule in ModelB.

The third field of ModelB has to be populated from ModelA's third field based on a combined find_by(combined key).

```
ModelB (field1, field2, field3 --> needs to be populated after validation against modelA)
```

In my scenario, I can't do a save on the object of modelB as it is embedded in a parent model. I can only save it as a whole, parent+ modelB. However I can do a ModelB.new().

My doubts:

1. ModelB.new() doesn't validate against the 'rule' and hence doesn't update the field3 upon validation. How can I solve this issue without doing a create! or save! ?
2. I am open to other ideas as well. Please let me know if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Why not just call `valid?` on the `ModelB.new()`?

Comment: Did try that. But that just doesn't update the field3 with the validated options! Even debugged it.

Comment: I would think you need a validation on ModelB that somehow refers back to the "rule" that comes from ModelA. If you are working with ModelB.new() do you have a reference back to ModelA that you could use as the starting point for a custom validator?